# Cannot start Activity from action bar menu even though i have added the activity element in manifest file

Tags: android

I am starting the activity after clicking on menu item in the action bar menu.
I have added the activity in manifest file also . I cannot find why there is ActivityNotFoundException. I have used intent to start new Activity. FragmentActivity extends Activity.

**MANIFEST FILE:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.myapplication">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.example.android.myapplication.FragmentActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY FILE:**

```
    package com.example.android.myapplication;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatCallback;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
    import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AppCompatCallback{

        private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
        private EditText mEditTextName;
        private EditText mEditTextEmail;
        private EditText mEditTextPhone;
        private Context context;
        Toast mToast;
        Intent mIntent;

       // private String mPreferenceFileName = getString(R.string.preference_file_key);
      //  private String mNameKey =  this.getString(R.string.name_key);
       // private String mPhoneKey = this.getString(R.string.phone_key);
        //private String mEmailKey = this.getString(R.string.email_key);

        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {}

        @Override
        public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {}

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
            return null;
        }
        private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
            delegate.installViewFactory();
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
            delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("myFile" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

            mEditTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            mEditTextPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
            mEditTextEmail= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.save:
                    mEditor.putString( "mNameKey",mEditTextName.getText().toString());
                    mEditor.putString( "mEmailKey",mEditTextPhone.getText().toString());
                    mEditor.putString( "mPhoneKey",mEditTextEmail.getText().toString());
                    mEditor.apply();
                    mToast = Toast.makeText(this,"saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mToast.show();
                    break;
                case R.id.Clear:
                    mEditTextName.setText("");
                    mEditTextEmail.setText("");
                    mEditTextPhone.setText("");
                    mToast = Toast.makeText(this,"Cleared",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mToast.show();
                    break;
                case R.id.retrieve:
                    if(mSharedPreferences.contains("mNameKey")){
                        mEditTextName.setText(mSharedPreferences.getString("mNameKey",""));
                    }
                    if(mSharedPreferences.contains("mEmailKey")){
                        mEditTextEmail.setText(mSharedPreferences.getString("mEmailKey",""));
                    }
                    if(mSharedPreferences.contains("mPhoneKey")){
                        mEditTextPhone.setText(mSharedPreferences.getString("mPhoneKey",""));
                    }
                    mToast = Toast.makeText(this,"Retrieved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mToast.show();
                    break;
                case R.id.FragementActivity:
                // HERE I CALL THE NEW ACTIVITY
                    try {
                        mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentActivity.class);
                        this.startActivity(mIntent);
                    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("tag","exception");
                    }
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

When i click on the FragmentActivity menu item I cannot start the new activity. Is it not possible to start new activity this way? Is there some alternative?

Comment: You should name your `FragmentActivity` something else. It's getting mixed up with a support class: `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of changing the class name or no need of removing this :-

```
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Instead **write your full qualified class** ( `yourPackagename.FragmentActivity` )name like

```
   (MainActivity.this,com.example.android.myapplication.FragmentActivity.class );
```

in the `explicit intent`   call  !!

Answer (score 2):

as @Mike M. already mentioned, you are trying to open `FragmentActivity` from the support package instead of your package, hence the issue

Solution :

1. You have to remove this import

   `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

and import your activity carefully.

2. you can use `setAction` as

   `mIntent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction("com.example.android.myapplication.FragmentActivity");
   this.startActivity(mIntent);`

Note : For second solution , To avoid the user to select app to complete the action, you need to add `DEFAULT` as `category` along with `intent-filter` for `FragmentActivity`